# Restore SQLServer Encrypted Backup on a server with higher version

Tags: sql-server, backup

I want to implement Backup Encryption. I have tested in Test server this process with success.
Before implementing on production I want to make sure that I am considering all risk.
The only thing that I have not managed its risk is when migrating the SQL Server to higher version.
Our current Version is 2019. I was thinking how can we restore old backups on SQL Server 2022 in any unplanned cases?
Is It possible? Or we can restore them only in same version?
When I tried to restore the certificate in 2022 I got this Error:

> The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or
> does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.

**What I have done:**

Step 1:Taking backup in SQL2019

```
BACKUP CERTIFICATE BackupEncryptionCertificate
TO FILE  = 'PathName\BackupCert.cert'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'PathName\BackupCert.PrivateKey', 
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'StrongPassword')
```

Step 2: Restore Certificate from Backup in SQL 2022

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE BackupEncryptionCert
 FROM FILE = 'PathName\BackupCert.cert'
 WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'PathName\BackupCert.PrivateKey', 
                    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ThePassword')
```

Comment: This scenario is fully supported, your issue lies in moving the certificate. What command did you use BACKUP the certificate on the 2019 server? what command are you using to create it on the 2022 server?

Comment: @StrayCatDBA Codes have been added